# How to detect UI thread on Android?

Tags: android

Is there a robust way to detect if `Thread.currentThread()` is the Android system UI thread in an application?
I would like to put some asserts in my model code that asserts that only one thread (**eg** the ui thread) accesses my state, to assure that no kind of synchronization is necessary.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41280460/878126

Answer (score 210):

Common practice to determine the UI Thread's identity is via [Looper#getMainLooper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html):

```
if (Looper.getMainLooper().getThread() == Thread.currentThread()) {
  // On UI thread.
} else {
  // Not on UI thread.
}
```

From API level 23 and up, there's a slightly more readable approach using new helper method [isCurrentThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html#isCurrentThread()) on the main looper:

```
if (Looper.getMainLooper().isCurrentThread()) {
  // On UI thread.
} else {
  // Not on UI thread.
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411022/how-to-check-if-current-thread-is-not-main-thread

This answer is nice too)

Answer (score 44):

I think that best way is this:

```
 if (Looper.getMainLooper().equals(Looper.myLooper())) {
     // UI thread
 } else {
     // Non UI thread
 }
```

Comment: No need to use `equals` since we're only comparing references, and on top of that, they're both static.

Answer (score 9):

As of API level 23 the [`Looper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html) has a nice helper method [`isCurrentThread`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html#isCurrentThread()). You could get the [`mainLooper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html#getMainLooper()) and see if it's the one for the current thread this way:

```
Looper.getMainLooper().isCurrentThread()
```

It's practically the same as:

```
Looper.getMainLooper().getThread() == Thread.currentThread()
```

but it could be a bit more readable and easier to remember.

Answer (score 7):

```
public boolean onUIThread() {
    return Looper.getMainLooper().isCurrentThread();

}
```

But it requires API level 23

Comment: Good to know about!

Answer (score 2):

Besides checking **looper**, if you ever tried to **logout** thread id in `onCreate()`, you could find the **UI thread(main thread)** id always equals to 1. Therefore

```
if (Thread.currentThread().getId() == 1) {
    // UI thread
}
else {
    // other thread
}
```

Comment: I cannot find any official documentation that corroborates that this is true, and will always be so. Do you have a link?

Comment: This is what I found in logcat when I want to monitor multi-thread behavior. You can try to output thread id

Comment: I would strongly recommend against this, as this value may be specific to your device and/or version of Android. Even if it were the case on every Android device right now, there is no guarantee that it will continue to be the case in later versions. Saving the thread ID in a class member when running onCreate() seems a little more reasonable to me.

Answer (score 2):

Nice extension for Kotlin:

```
val Thread.isMain get() = Looper.getMainLooper().thread == Thread.currentThread()
```

So you just call:

```
Thread.currentThread().isMain
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use the `runOnUiThread` method in the `Activity` class?See..

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29

Comment: My application is working, but, it has several authors and is becomming rather big and complex. What I want to do is to add an extra safety net, an assert that catches the misstake if somebody is calling a method that is designed to only be called from the GUI-thread from another thread.

Comment: I am currently fixing a bug where using runOnUiThread causes the UX to flash.