# How to check if current thread is not main thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I need to check if the thread running a certain piece of code is the main (UI) thread or not. How can I achieve this?

Comment: example to demonstrate with thread example http://code2concept.blogspot.in/2015/02/androidhow-to-find-on-which-thread-code.html

Answer (score 820, accepted):

```
Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()
```

if this returns true, then you're on the UI thread!

Comment: what if the current thread has no looper defined?

Comment: @jackiszhp: I assume Looper.myLooper() returns null if no looper setup. I assume Looper.getMainLooper() never returns null so then the equality test will evaluate to false. And, that would be what you want. The current thread is not the main thread.

Answer (score 146):

you can use below code  to know if current thread is UI/Main thread or not

```
if(Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()) {
   // Current Thread is Main Thread.
}
```

or you can also use this

```
if(Looper.getMainLooper().getThread() == Thread.currentThread()) {
   // Current Thread is Main Thread.
}
```

[Here is similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8714032/519718)

Comment: Should one consider the latter as the safer option as there is no guarantee that any arbitrary thread is associated with a Looper (assuming that the main thread is always associated with a looper)?

Comment: `Looper.myLooper()` will return null if the thread is not associated with a Looper. So both are safe and have the same result but the first one is a little bit slower while it searches inside a map to find out the looper and its associated thread and do some other stuff .

Answer (score 76):

The best way is the clearest, most robust way: *

```
Thread.currentThread().equals( Looper.getMainLooper().getThread() )
```

Or, if the runtime platform is API level 23 (Marshmallow 6.0) or higher:

```
Looper.getMainLooper().isCurrentThread()
```

See the [Looper API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html).  Note that calling `Looper.getMainLooper()` involves synchronization (see the [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/android-6.0.0_r1/core/java/android/os/Looper.java#112)).  You might want to avoid the overhead by storing the return value and reusing it.

* *credit [greg7gkb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3273018/2402790) and [2cupsOfTech](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34052602)*

Comment: What do you mean by "under API 23 or higher"? That doesn't make much sense to me..Also the exact same answer was posted by AAnkit, below..

Comment: @Mike Thanks, I fixed the API bit.  AAnkit actually favours `Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()`, which I think is less clear.  I credit greg7gkb.

Comment: should this be a comparison with == or equals() as Android Studio is raising a warning ?

Comment: @2cupsOfTech On 2nd thought, that’s good advice. Currently both tests are the same at runtime because [Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) does not override `equals`, and so falls back to `==`, but that could change in future. So I corrected the answer.

Answer (score 29):

Summarizing the solutions, I think that's the best one:

```
boolean isUiThread = VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.M 
    ? Looper.getMainLooper().isCurrentThread()
    : Thread.currentThread() == Looper.getMainLooper().getThread();
```

And, if you wish to run something on the UI thread, you can use this:

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       //this runs on the UI thread
    }
});
```

Comment: Other answers around Handler recommend using ".postDelayed()" rather than ".post()".  What is the main difference and can you mention why you recommended using ".post()"?

Comment: @AJW Sure, here are the docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler#post(java.lang.Runnable) https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20java.lang.Object,%20long) . You use the postDelayed if you wish for the runnable to run at least X ms fro now.

Comment: Excellent, I appreciate the info.

Comment: @androiddeveloper How can i run something not in the main thread???

Comment: @KJEjava48 Many ways to do it. The basic one is to create a new `Thread` class and either implement `run` on it or provide a `Runnable` instance to it, and then call `start()` on this `Thread` instance. In Kotlin there is a very short way to do it, using just `thread{ runCodeHere() }` .

Answer (score 8):

**You can check**

```
if(Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()) {
   // You are on mainThread 
}else{
// you are on non-ui thread
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**First of all check It is main Thread or not**

> In Kotlin

```
fun isRunningOnMainThread(): Boolean {
    return Thread.currentThread() == Looper.getMainLooper().thread
}
```

> In Java

```
static boolean isRunningOnMainThread() {
  return Thread.currentThread().equals(Looper.getMainLooper().getThread());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Allow me to preface this with:
I acknowledged this post has the 'Android' tag, however, my search had nothing to do with 'Android' and this was my top result. To that end, for the **non-Android** SO Java users landing here, don't forget about:

```
public static void main(String[] args{
    Thread.currentThread().setName("SomeNameIChoose");
    /*...the rest of main...*/
}
```

After setting this, elsewhere in your code, you can easily check if you're about to execute on the main thread with:

```
if(Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("SomeNameIChoose"))
{
    //do something on main thread
}
```

A bit embarrassed I had searched before remembering this, but hopefully it will help someone else!

Answer (score 3):

just log this line, it should print "main".

**Thread.currentThread().name**

Answer (score 3):

In addition to all previous answers

```kotlin
inline fun <T> ensureNotOnMainThread(block: () -> T): T {
    check(Thread.currentThread() != Looper.getMainLooper().thread) { "This function cannot be called on main thread" }
    return block()
}
```

allows to wrap any method with it, following example :

```kotlin
fun isInDataBase(id: String) = ensureNotOnMainThread { db.contains(id) }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can verify it in android ddms logcat where process id will be same but thread id will be different.

Answer (score 1):

`Xamarin.Android` port: (*`C#`*)

```
public bool IsMainThread => Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.M
    ? Looper.MainLooper.IsCurrentThread
    : Looper.MyLooper() == Looper.MainLooper;
```

Usage:

```
if (IsMainThread) {
    // you are on UI/Main thread
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So another answer to join the company, for some extension file in kotlin:

```
import android.os.Looper.getMainLooper
import java.lang.Thread.currentThread

val Thread.isMain get() = getMainLooper().thread == this

val isThreadMain get() = getMainLooper().thread == currentThread()
```

Answer (score -3):

A simple Toast message works also as a quick check.

Comment: How??  Can u pls show that Toast code

Comment: `Toast.makeText(activity, "Hello main thread", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Answer (score -3):

A coroutines-based, Android-agnostic approach:

```
val onMainThread: Boolean
    get() = Thread.currentThread() === try {
        runBlocking(Dispatchers.Main.immediate) {
            Thread.currentThread()
        }
    } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
        // No main dispatcher has been registered; not in an Android context?
        null
    }
```

Comment: Care to elaborate @Renetik? Can you suggest a better solution in a non-Android context?

Answer (score -7):

You can try Thread.currentThread().isDaemon()

Comment: I am not sure the UI thread is a daemon but I will believe you on this one. But how will you make the difference with a Daemon Thread that I could (but should not) create.

Comment: I tested in my web app, it shows that UI thread is a Daemon thread. I put some debug break points  in eclipse environment and verified it. Thread detail shown as Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-7,5,main]. Clicked on some UI pages and checked the debug point.

Comment: Also, even if in the thread name details its showing 'main' but calling setDaemon(true) on thread object will make it daemon.

Comment: You didn't read the good part ... I wasn't doubting (completly) about it being a Daemon, I was telling that you can't make the differences with an other Daemon thread like this.

Comment: Put another way: a main thread may be a daemon thread, but not all daemon threads are the main thread. (Identifying the main thread is what is being asked here.)

Comment: Also, it's important to note that the main thread being a daemon is not under programmer control, and an API or VM change could result in this assertion being untrue.