# Android Java : Are methods called from an AsyncTask also running in the background thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

On main Activity, I do the following to have these methods run in the background thread.

```
private void doInBackground() {
      final Activity a = this;
      AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            bindDb();
            new MessageSynchronizer(a);
            NotifHelper.cancelNotifications(a);
            MessageHelper.updateMyLastSeen();
            versioning();
         }
      });
}
```

Then I want to know if the following method, called from above is running in the UiThread or the thread which called it above.

```
private void bindDb() {
      DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
      databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
      databaseHelper.getDatabaseName();
      databaseHelper.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's on the background thread, i.e. the thread used by `ASyncTask`. That's due to pure Java execution semantics: a method being invoked by a method running on a thread gets executed on the same thread.

You can also verify this by checking the current thread as shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411022/how-to-check-if-current-thread-is-not-main-thread).

Comment: Proper, the post you linked to will be helpful.