# How can I intentionally crash my Xamarin Android application for not using RunOnUiThread?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-runonuithread

I know this sounds like a weird question.

I have a Xamarin.Android app. I'm going through my code and cleaning up stuff that was too aggressively wrapped with calls to `RunOnUiThread`. My understanding is that code that runs in response to UI events, for example, is already on the UI thread and therefore doesn't need to be wrapped. I don't like the idea of `RunOnUiThread` calls just sprinkled everywhere like magical pixie dust.

I've removed a bunch of these calls, and preserved the ones I think are necessary. When I run the app, everything works great. But *not even a single crash on the first try* seemed almost too good to be true, so as a sanity check, I tried to intentionally crash the app by adding UI update code in places where I expected it to be required to be wrapped by `RunOnUiThread`. However, nothing I do causes that effect!

This makes me concerned that there is some magic happening somewhere that is preventing me from seeing a problem.

The last thing I tried, which I thought would surely crash the app, was to use a `Java.Util.Timer` to execute a `Java.Util.TimerTask` that sets the Alpha on an `ImageView` to 0.5. But still the app hums merrily along!

Now I am totally suspicious that something -- maybe some new OS feature -- is silently fixing things but that customers running in some other configuration will experience crashes. I want to see the error so that I can have confidence that when I don't see it, things are OK.

So, what can I do to intentionally get the `Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views` error?

Comment: Maybe checking in which thread you are can be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411022/how-to-check-if-current-thread-is-not-main-thread

Comment: @Piovezan, thank you, that is really useful. I was able to confirm that the code that runs in a TimerTask is indeed not running in the UI thread. But still, changing a UI component produced no ill effects. This only heightens my concern that something is going on that is "helping" to prevent errors that might occur in a different environment. I'd really love to figure this out.