# Android Is it safe to assume the "main/UI thread" ID is always 1?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm working on a jar file that gets included in other applications, and it has to be very robust.

in the jar, i have an object, say `SomeView`, which takes in an Android Context, tries to create a `Handler` object, and will touch views, so it needs to be initialized from the main thread. How can i guarantee 100% that they won't initialize my `SomeView` in the wrong thread?

such as:

```
public class SomeView {
    Handler mHandler;
    public SomeView(Context context) {
        mHandler = new Handler();
    }
}
```

i.e. will `if (Thread.currentThread().getId() != 1) failSafely();` in the constructor work?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848575/how-to-detect-ui-thread-on-android

Comment: @MTilsted thanks for the find. i also wanted to know that in my particular case, if i only wanted to check the thread ID, as opposed to the object, it would work better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can i guarantee 100% that they won't initialize my SomeView in the wrong thread?

Wrap your code in a `Runnable` and use `runOnUiThread()` (on an `Activity`) or `post()` (on `SomeView`) to ensure that it is run on the main application thread.

> i.e. will if (Thread.currentThread().getId() != 1) failSafely(); in the constructor work?

I certainly would not count on that.

Use `Looper.getMainLooper().getThread()` to get the `Thread` object that represents the main application thread. But, I'd just wrap the thread-sensitive blocks in `Runnables` and have those blocks run on the main application thread.

Comment: as for your first suggestion: The constructor for `SomeView` is `SomeView(Context context)`, which allows for a global application context, which doesn't have any notion of `runOnUiThread()` (only `Activity` does). and if i use `post()`, i'm assuming i have to use a `Handler` object? If the developer accidentally instantiated that `mHandler` from my constructor of `SomeView` on the wrong thread, it'll crash with "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()"

Comment: @DavidT.: "which allows for a global application context" -- do not create instances of a `View` using the `Application` context. "if i use post(), i'm assuming i have to use a Handler object?" -- `post()` is also a method on `View`.

Comment: as for your second suggestion, may i assume that 100% of the time, even running on millions of regular Android stock devices, that`Thread.currentThread().getId() != Looper.getMainLooper().getThread().getId()` is the correct check?